# Вложенный абстрактный класс

Tags: java

1. Может ли кто-нибудь привести пример, когда следует использовать вложенный абстрактный класс.
2. Почему наличие вложенного абстрактного класса не делает сам класс абстрактным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Его следует использовать, если хочется сделать иерархию внутренних классов, а они должны иметь доступ к данным внешнего класса и не хочется нарушать инкапсуляцию, а внутренние классы хочется спрятать от чужих глаз.

Например,

```
class MySomethingManager {
    private int privateData = 777;
    private DataProcessingStrategy currentProcessor = new NullStrategy();

    public void process() {
        currentProcessor.processData();
    }

    // some code

    private abstract class DataProcessingStrategy {
        public void processData();
    }

    private class NullStrategy extends DataProcessingStrategy {
        public void processData() {
            // nothing to do
        }
    }

    private class DecreaseStrategy extends DataProcessingStrategy {
        public void processData() {
            privateData--;
        }
    }
}
```

Разумеется пример вырожденный: я мог бы использовать интерфейс вместо абстрактного класса, но если бы была бы какая-то общая для всех реализаций логика, то тогда как раз абстрактный класс и получается.

2) А почему должно? Внешний клас всё ещё можно создавать. А внутренний будет нельзя инстанциировать.

Например, что мешает вам создать экземпляр класса Hello? Ничто. А вот попробуйте-ка создать AnyClass.

```
public class Hello {

    private abstract class AnyClass {
    }

}
```